# Function for generating in-line TailwindCSS classNames only works sometimes (React, NextJS)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I am using TailwindCSS to style a web application. The annoying thing is that if I want to add before: and after: psuedo-elements, I have to do it individually.

For example, I am styling a navigation drop-down button:

```
<span className={'block relative border-2 w-full h-3 content-["test"]' + tagProps('before', ['block', 'absolute', 'top-2', 'border-2', 'w-full', 'h-0', 'content-[""]']) + tagProps('after', ['block', 'absolute', 'bottom-2', 'border-2', 'w-full', 'h-0', 'content-[""]'])}></span>
```

Using this function:

```
const tagProps = (tag, prop) => {
let x = ' ';
for(const property of prop)
{
    x = x.concat(tag.concat(':').concat((property).concat(' ')));
}
return(x);
```

And for whatever reason, the styles only apply at complete randomness. If I shut down my browser, close VSCode, and reboot it, there is about a 25% chance the styles will apply. I am using a function for this because for whatever reason, TailwindCSS allows custom properties inside brackets (e.g. "content-["sample"] ) but does not allow that for pseudo-elements (e.g. before:["block absolute bottom-2"] ).

If I were to type out every psuedo-element, this is how long the single line would be:

```
<span className='block relative border-2 w-full h-3 content-["test"] before:block before:absolute before:top-2 before:border-2 before:w-full before:h-0 before:content-[""] after:block after:absolute after:top-2 after:border-2 after:w-full after:h-0 after:content-[""]'></span>
```

This seems insane to me. Another pet-peeve I've noticed is I cannot make the JSX statement multi-line (if I use the function to generate the classnames).

How is this library so highly-acclaimed? How is this any better than using CSS modules in nextjs?

I would appreciate any pointers and suggestions for how to go about this.

Comment: Ironically I just noticed that using a function only decreased the entire character count by only 1, but I still find it's easier to read and edit than just doing before: a hundred times.

Comment: Be aware about how Tailwind does class detection, I think this may be part of your problem if you are using dynamic class names, https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Comment: You can use Safelisting, https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes which may help in your situation.

Comment: @stickyuser This is exactly what I was looking for, you should've posted it as an answer so I could've marked it as solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind doesn't detect dynamic class names

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names

Safe-listing can be used to generate class-names for scenarios like this

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

Credits go to @stickyuser